# Regex for page sorting query string

Tags: regex

I am trying to match

- "SomeField:asc"
- "SomeField:desc"
- "SomeField:asc,SomeField:asc"
- "SomeField:desc,SomeField:desc" ...

Does not match if

- ""
- SomeField:desc,SomeField
- SomeField,SomeField:asc
- SomeField:desc,SomeField:des, (exta comma)

I have current regex `[A-Za-z]+:(asc|desc),` but I am stuck. I am sure it is really simple regex but I am new to this so please be patient! Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/e36uAk/1) `^(?:[A-Za-z]+:(?:asc|desc),?)+$`

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Inside a non capturing group `(?:`
- One or more characters `[A-Za-z]+`
- Followed by a color `:`
- Inside a non capturing group `(?:`
- asc or desc `asc|desc`
- with an optional comma `,?`
- the outer optional group one or more times `+`
- Unitl the end of the string `$`

Comment: This is a really clear explanation thank you! However there is one problem. It seems the comma should not be optional, it is only not required if the non capturing group is the last. For example this regex will match "asdfasdf:ascasdfasd:desc"

Comment: `^(?:[A-Za-z]+:(?:asc|desc))(?:,[A-Za-z]+:(?:asc|desc))*$` WIll not allow trailing comma however, is there a better pattern so I can avoid makinng repetive regex

Comment: Then I think you can check if it does not end with a comma:
`^(?:[A-Za-z]+:(?:asc|desc),)?(?:[A-Za-z]+:(?:asc|desc))$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Yj4h9A/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick:

```
([\w+]+:(asc|desc))(,([\w+]+:(asc|desc)))*
```

It will match one or more fields, ignoring those that do not meet the spec.